# What is the preferred method of submitting a bug report on macOS?

Tags: debugging, osx

On a Mac, when an application dies, a GUI window comes up with a place to type in some stuff if you want to and then hit "Report".  Something goes off somewhere to someone but I'm 99% sure nothing goes to the emacs bug report mailing list.  The window appears to have some really useful information like stack traceback, etc.

The flip side is the `report-emacs-bug` command also has a lot of useful information that would help understand the problem.

What is the preferred, most effective way, to combine these two sources of information?  Should I just copy what is in the macOS GUI window and paste it somewhere in the emacs-bug-report or is there a file somewhere that contains the same information that I could attach to the email that `report-emacs-bug` sends out?

Comment: Unfortunately, a crash report from the operating system is of zero benefit to the Emacs development team.  What they really need is (1) a `gdb` \ `lldb` full backtrace and a series of steps to reproduce the issue, or (2) just a series of steps to reproduce the issue.  And, of of course, the version of Emacs, operating system, etc.  A `gdb` \ `lldb` full backtrace requires building Emacs from source, setting the starting directory as `.../src`, launching Emacs with `gdb` / `lldb`, and a few other things ....

Comment: @lawlist Hmm... You bring up good point.  I debugged system dumps from system dump files.  It isn't fun but it is do-able.  With AIX, they broke core files to the point that they were no longer useful.  I assume macOS produces core files.  Do you know if they are useful and where they are hidden?  I build my emacs myself so I could build it with debug (if it isn't that way already).